Kotlin, cannot create instance of class Viewmodel
I am new to MVVM architecture, I have tried with different options but still getting same exception "cannot able to create an instance ViewModel".
I am using Android Studio Iguana
below is my VideoActivity:
class VideoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: VideoViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(VideoViewModel::class.java)
        
        val videos= listOf(
            Video(id = 1, url = "url1.mp4"),
            Video(id = 1, url = "url2.mp4"),
            Video(id = 1, url = "url3.mp4"),
            Video(id = 1, url = "url4.mp4"),
            Video(id = 1, url = "url5.mp4"),
        )

        viewModel.downloadVideos(videos)

        viewModel.videos.observe(this) { downloadedVideos ->
            if (downloadedVideos.isNotEmpty()) {
                viewModel.playNextVideo()
            }
        }
    }
}

below is my VideoRepository class
    class VideoRepository(private val context: Context) {
       
        suspend fun downloadVideos(videos: List<Video>): List<Video> {
            val downloadedVideos = mutableListOf<Video>()
            for (video in videos) {
                val filePath = downloadVideo(video.url)
                if (filePath.isNotBlank()) {
                    video.downloadStatus = DownloadStatus.DOWNLOADED
                    video.filePath = filePath
                    downloadedVideos.add(video)
                }
            }
            return downloadedVideos
        }
    
        private suspend fun downloadVideo(videoUrl: String): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val url = URL(videoUrl)
                val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                connection.connect()
    
                val inputStream: InputStream = connection.inputStream
                val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "video_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.mp4")
                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
    
                val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                var bytesRead: Int
                while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                }
    
                outputStream.flush()
                outputStream.close()
                inputStream.close()
    
                file.absolutePath
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                ""
            }
        }
    
        fun playVideo(video: Video) {
            val videoView = (context as VideoActivity).findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.video_view)
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video.filePath))
            videoView.start()
        }
    }

class VideoViewModel(var repository: VideoRepository) : ViewModel(){

    private val _videos = MutableLiveData<List<Video>>()
    val videos:LiveData<List<Video>> = _videos

    private lateinit var videoView: VideoView

    private var currentVideoIndex = 0
    fun downloadVideos(videos: List<Video>){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val downloadVideos = repository.downloadVideos(videos)
            _videos.postValue(downloadVideos)
        }
    }

    fun playNextVideo(){
        currentVideoIndex = (currentVideoIndex + 1) % (videos.value?.size ?: 1)
        val video = videos.value?.get(currentVideoIndex)
        video?.let{
            repository.playVideo(it)
        }
    }  
}

App Gradle Dependencies:
implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
implementation(libs.androidx.material3)

implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0")
implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)

Below is the exception which I am getting
Process: com.android, PID: 4717
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android/com.android.main.VideoActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.android.main.VideoViewModel
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3825)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3971)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2389)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8261)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.android.main.VideoViewModel
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:201)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:320)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:302)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:276)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:184)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:150)
                                                                                                        at com.android.main.VideoActivity.onCreate(VideoActivity.kt:20)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8516)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8480)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1418)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3971) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2389) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8261) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954) 
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.android.adbeets.main.VideoViewModel.<init> []
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3325)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:3063)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:199)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:320) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:302) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:276) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:184) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:150) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.adbeets.main.VideoActivity.onCreate(VideoActivity.kt:20) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8516) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8480) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1418) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3971) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2389) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8261) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954) 
2024-04-09 12:06:35.424 24478-30209 ActivityManagerWrapper  com.miui.home                        E

Could anyone help me on this issue,
Thanks inAdvance

Your viewModel definition is an old one, try to use the new approach to initialize your viewModel.
Add these dependencies to your project;
def activity_version = "1.8.2"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version"

Remove your viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(VideoViewModel::class.java) line
Update your private lateinit var viewModel: VideoViewModel to private val viewModel: VideoViewModel by viewModels()
Hope this helps.

Mustafa,Thanks for your response, when I try to add above dependency getting exception Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find activityx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.2.


You should copy&paste the artifact from the answer. activityx.activity:activity-ktx is not what was suggested.

Please follow this page to implement the library https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity

Reason is that default viewModel providers cannot construct viewModel which contains properties in primary constructor (excepts for application class). I would recommend you some DI library (hilt for example).
Solution without DI
If you don't want to implement DI right now just change your viewModel's like this:
class VideoViewModel(
application: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
   val repository: VideoRepository = VideoRepository(application)
}

This is just quick workaround but i recommend using DI.
Solution with DI
Add plugin into your root build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
  //Plugin is taken from google() repository
  id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.51.1" apply false
  
  //Keep in mind to use compatible versions of ksp and kotlin
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.23" apply false
  id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.23-1.0.20" apply false
}

then update your app's build.gradle.kts, keep in mind you have to use same version of hilt:
plugins {
  id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
  id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
    val hiltVersion = "2.51.1"
    val hiltCompilerVersion = "1.2.0"
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hiltVersion")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-common:$hiltCompilerVersion")
    
    //using ksp but it's still possible to use kapt
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hiltVersion")
    ksp("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hiltCompilerVersion")
}


After you sync your gradle you have to adjust your code for dependency injection, follow the docs i mentioned.
Annotate your application class with @HiltAndroidApp and also don't forget to declare it in Manifest.xml:
@HiltAndroidApp
class ExampleApplication : Application() { ... }

Manifest:
<application
    android:name=".ExampleApplication"/>

After that annotate your VideoActivity with @AndroidEntryPoint annotation and update how you are constructing the viewModel:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class VideoActivity : AppCompatActivity() { 
   private val viewModel: VideoViewModel by viewModels()
}

Update your viewModel with annotations to tell the hilt how to construct it:
@HiltViewModel
class VideoViewModel @Inject constructor(
val repository: VideoRepository
) : ViewModel(){ ... }

And for your VideoRepository too to tell the hilt how to construct it:
///In case you want only one single instance of repository
@Singleton
class VideoRepository @Inject constructor(
@ApplicationContext private val context: Context
) { ... }

With this you are able to have clean MVVM architecture using dependency injection for better dependencies management. I didn't explained all the details because it's all in the documentation.
Hope this helps.

You should use ksp instead of kapt. Also, you need to annotate the Application with @HiltAndroidApp. And while you're at it you should use the newest hilt version.

Thanks for your response, what we need to add in Application class, please do let me know

@Naveen I updated the DI solution in my answer.
@Leviathan Thanks, didn't know that hilt has support for ksp too.

@MiroslavHýbler, thanks for updating the code, I am getting below exception after updating the code  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilationContext.(org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.storage.FileToPathConverter, org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.storage.FileToPathConverter, boolean, org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.CompilationTransaction, org.jetbrains.kotlin.build.report.ICReporter, boolean, boolean, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker)'

@Naveen Try clean and rebuild your project, and also make sure to use compatible ksp and kotlin versions, i used newest ones in my answer.
I didn't experienced this build crash myself, i believe it's just some temporary crash which can be solved by rebuild, or after clearing Android Studio cache and restart.

@Miroslav, KotlinVersion which I am using in the project is 1.9.0, KSP versions are which you have provided I am using those versions,   I have tried cleaning, rebuild the project I have also restarted the studio,  but I am getting the same issue

@Naveen That's problem because those are not compatible. See this https://github.com/google/ksp/releases?page=3, for kotlin 1.9.0 you have to use ksp  e.g. 1.9.0-1.0.13

@MiroslavHýbler, after updating KSP, i am getting below exception   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension'.

Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.9.0.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/1.9.0/compiler-1.9.0.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/1.9.0/compiler-1.9.0.pom
Required by:
project :app


@Naveen I am getting lost now. You have to use compatible versions of ksp, kotlin and kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion when using compose. You said you are using kotlin 1.9.0 so for this you have to use ksp 1.9.0-1.0.13 and for kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = 1.5.2. Look here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin, there is compatibility list between compose and kotlin.

@MiroslavHýbler, Actually I am using compitable versions, I have also added this dependency implementation("androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.9.0") and checked still getting the above issue

@Naveen Why did you added compose compiler like this? To enable compose buildFeatures { compose = true } is used but that's different problem. Where did you get  version 1.9.0 of compose compiler? Based on source repo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.compose.compiler/compiler actual is 1.5.11 which is for kotlin 1.9.23. You have to use compatible version of compose compiler (for kotlin 1.9.0 it is 1.5.2) based on this list: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin.

@MiroslavHýbler, Could you please check this link once,    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78332166/kotlin-videos-not-playing-when-there-is-no-internet-connection-offline
