Kotlin - videos not playing when there is no internet connection (offline)
I have tried with different cases, videos not playing when there is no internet connection. I have debugged it, path is coming fine.
FilePath: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.XXXXX/files/Movies/video_1713236799994.mp4

Below is my application class,
@HiltAndroidApp
class AdbeetsApplication : Application() {
}

below is my data class,
data class Video(
    val id: Int,
    val url: String,
    var downloadStatus: DownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.NOT_STARTED,
    var filePath: String = ""
    )

enum class DownloadStatus{
    NOT_STARTED,
    DOWNLOADING,
    DOWNLOADED,
    ERROR
}

interface VideoPlaybackListener {
    fun playVideo(videoUrl: String)
}

fun isInternetAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
        val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network) ?: return false
        return capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
    } else {
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo ?: return false
        return networkInfo.isConnected
    }
}

Below is my Activity class,
@AndroidEntryPoint
class VideoActivity : AppCompatActivity(), VideoPlaybackListener {
    private val viewModel: VideoViewModel by viewModels()
    private var isVideoPlaying = false
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        hideStatusBar()
        if (isInternetAvailable(applicationContext)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please wait, loading Video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            viewModel.setPlaybackListener(this)
            val videos= listOf(
                Video(id = 1, url = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"),
                Video(id = 2, url = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"),
                Video(id = 3, url = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4"),
                Video(id = 4, url = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4"),
                Video(id = 5, url = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4"),
            )

            viewModel.downloadVideos(videos)

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No internet connection. Playing offline videos...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            viewModel.loadOfflineVideos()
        }


        viewModel.videos.observe(this) { downloadedVideos ->
            if (downloadedVideos.isNotEmpty()) {
                viewModel.playNextVideo()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No videos available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (isVideoPlaying) {
            viewModel.playNextVideo()
        }
    }

    override fun playVideo(videoUrl: String) {
        val videoView = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.video_view)
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl))
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener {
            viewModel.playNextVideo()
        }
        videoView.start()
        isVideoPlaying = true
    }

    private fun hideStatusBar() {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        actionBar?.hide()
    }
}

Below is my repository class,
@Singleton
class VideoRepository @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) {
    private var playbackListener: VideoPlaybackListener? = null

    suspend fun downloadVideosIfNeeded(videos: List<Video>): List<Video> {
        val downloadedVideos = mutableListOf<Video>()
        for (video in videos) {
            // Check if the video file exists in the internal storage
            if (video.filePath.isBlank()) {
                // Video file does not exist, download it
                val filePath = downloadVideo(video.url)
                if (filePath.isNotBlank()) {
                    video.downloadStatus = DownloadStatus.DOWNLOADED
                    video.filePath = filePath
                    downloadedVideos.add(video)
                }
            } else {
                downloadedVideos.add(video)
            }
        }
        return downloadedVideos
    }

    private suspend fun downloadVideo(videoUrl: String): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val url = URL(videoUrl)
            val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            connection.connect()

            val inputStream: InputStream = connection.inputStream
            val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "video_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.mp4")
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)

            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var bytesRead: Int
            while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            }

            outputStream.flush()
            outputStream.close()
            inputStream.close()

            file.absolutePath
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            ""
        }
    }

    fun setPlaybackListener(listener: VideoPlaybackListener) {
        playbackListener = listener
    }
    fun playVideo(video: Video) {
        playbackListener?.playVideo(video.filePath)
    }


        fun getOfflineVideos(): List<Video> {
    val videos = mutableListOf<Video>()
    val directory = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
    directory?.listFiles()?.forEach { file ->
        if (file.isFile && file.extension == "mp4") {
            val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.android.myadbeetsapp.fileprovider", file)
            val video = Video(id = videos.size + 1, url = "", filePath = uri.toString(), downloadStatus = DownloadStatus.DOWNLOADED)
            videos.add(video)
        }
    }
    return videos
}

}

Below is my XML file,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.VideoActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

below is the FileProvider XML file,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>

below is the exception, when I try to play video offline(open app next time without internet connection), while creating instance of VideoViewModel in VideoActivity
cannot find local variable 'videoUrl'

     private val viewModel: VideoViewModel by viewModels()
    Method threw 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldException' exception.
        java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field viewModel in class

below is the exception coming when I tried with FileProvider,
 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.android.XXXX, PID: 16026
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.myadbeetsapp/com.android.XXXX.main.VideoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.android.XXXX.provider
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3825)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3971)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2389)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8261)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.android.myadbeetsapp.provider
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getFileProviderPathsMetaData(FileProvider.java:688)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:719)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:669)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:451)
                                                                                                        at com.android.XXXX.main.VideoRepository.getOfflineVideos(VideoRepository.kt:113)
                                                                                                        at com.android.XXXX.main.VideoViewModel.loadOfflineVideos(VideoViewModel.kt:46)
                                                                                                        at com.android.XXXX.main.VideoActivity.onCreate(VideoActivity.kt:32)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8516)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8480)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1418)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3971) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2389) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8261) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954) 

When there is internet connection videos playing in loop perfectly fine, but when there is no internet connection videos are not playing.
Point here is first time we can use internet, from next time if the internet is not available then the videos should play from offline storage.
Also I have tried with File Provider, but videos not playing in loop
Could anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Is the Provider correctly configured in AndroidManifest.xml?
Can you share what is relevant about your viewmodel?
